# Two different relationships and one view

Tags: 6, nodes, views

I would need to combine two content types into one view. Well this is easy but where it gets more tricky is that other content type would need to user relationship that connects to another (third) content type. So how can I have view that gets content from two content types and another content type requires relationship (another one doesn't)? All suggestions are welcome!

I'm using Drupal 6, panels and views.

EDIT:

So two content types, another is feed_item content type (using Feeds import module), another is called blog_post content type.

Third is blog_info content where is info about blogger and the blog. From this content type I would need to get info. So blog_post content type is related to blog_info and from there I need to get field blog_age.

Common fields I show in view are body and title from blog_post & feed_item. So additional field field that I want to show is the blog_age field. This field is in blog_info content type and is only related to blog_post.

Comment: Could you explain more how to content types are connected. What are they called and on which content type is the node reference field etc?

Comment: I edited the original question by adding some content type & field names. Hopefully is more clearer now. If not, I can add more info.

Comment: How do you reference the content types to each other?

Comment: With relationship.

Comment: How do you reference feed_item to blog post? You say "blog_post content type is related to blog_info" and "blog_info content type and is only related to blog_post". Can you specify like this forexample, blog_post has a node reference field which points at blog_info, feed_item has a node reference field which points at X, etc?

Comment: Well blog_info has author field which is same as blog_post author. Feed_item doesn't have any reference anywhere. It just gets feed items and shows them individually.